# How can I draw rectangles with sharp edges. Mine are faded?

Tags: android, draw, fading

I try to draw 2 adjacent rectangle in a textview, inside a liste view.
My rectangles are fading, and I don't understand why. I tried many walkover, but none are succesfull .

here is the code, in the adapter :

```
Bitmap bg = Bitmap.createBitmap( width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bg);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        //paint.setAntiAlias(false);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FF99FF66"));
        canvas.drawRect(0,0, barWidth, height, paint );
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FF80CBC4"));
        canvas.drawRect(barWidth + 1, 0, width, height, paint );
        viewHolder.tvscore.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bg));
```

Here is an image of what  I get :
http://www.seusoft.com/images/StackOverflow.gif

Notes : width is the measured width of the textview, barWidth is the width of the left rectangle.

Thanks for any help

Comment: paint.setAntiAlias(true); try this

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't change anything. As you can see, the antiAlias property is commented out in my source, because I tried true and false value without any result.